# generating POST request, curl_setopt, http_build_query: a data loss

Tags: php

Im generating a POST request:

```
$data['v'] = '2';
$data['file'] = gz compressed data

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

After this, the "file" field gets lost - it wont arrive to the server, all others do. What can I do?

Comment: What is url? To  solve the issue

Comment: it doesnt really matter :)

Answer (score 2):

When uploading files, `curl` is expecting the full path to your file (don't forget to prepend the '@' symbol), and not the binary data:

```
$data = array(
    'file' => "@/path/to_your_file_not_binary_data",
    'v' => '2'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Also, if you need to specify the `Content-Type` header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
```